# How does one control absolute thickness of the edges of vertices in graphs? Graph orientation?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In preparing a talk I discovered that some of my graphs did not render well, when displayed on a projector because the default lines in graphs are too narrow.  Although I was able to fix this for edge thickness, but using a second VertexStyle-> Directive[Thickness[0.00001], Black] does not work no matter how small I specify the thickness, I can't seem to put a thick black border around the edges of the vertices.

I also want to control the orientation of the graph so that it "grows" from bottom to top.  I have done this with two Rotate functions, one for the labels and one for the graph.  However, this seems awkward to me.  Is there a built in option to do this so that the orientation of labels works appropriately?

My code is as follows:

```
rotateLabel[lab_] := Rotate[lab, 180 Degree]; tree1 = 
Rotate[TreeGraph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 6}, 
EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02], Black], 
VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 25], 
VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Red, 
 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Red}, VertexSize -> Large, 
VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["c", Center, rotateLabel], 
 2 -> Placed["a", Center, rotateLabel], 
 3 -> Placed["d", Center, rotateLabel], 
 4 -> Placed["f", Center, rotateLabel], 
 5 -> Placed["b", Center, rotateLabel], 
 6 -> Placed["e", Center, rotateLabel]}], 180 Degree]; tree2 = 
 Rotate[TreeGraph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 6}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02], Black], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 25], 
VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Yellow, 
 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Red}, VertexSize -> Large, 
VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["c", Center, rotateLabel], 
 2 -> Placed["a", Center, rotateLabel], 
 3 -> Placed["d", Center, rotateLabel], 
 4 -> Placed["f", Center, rotateLabel], 
 5 -> Placed["b", Center, rotateLabel], 
 6 -> Placed["e", Center, rotateLabel]}], 180 Degree];
 GraphicsGrid[{{tree1}, {tree2}}, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

Thanks in advance to those more clever than

Comment: To control the thickness of edges of the vertices use `EdgeForm`. So for exampe: `VertexStyle->{1 -> {EdgeForm[Thick], Yellow}, ...}`.

Comment: That works but doesn't quite give me the control I was looking for.  However, your suggestion did lead to the control I was looking for by substituting in VertexStyle the following works beautifully:  VertexStyle -> {EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.02], Black]], {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Yellow, 
 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Red} Just what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: @StuartPoss you might consider using `Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1],Black]` to have a line thickness of 1 print point regardless of the size of your image

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for the tip.